# Is it possible to customise the ugly little Flash "Local Settings" dialog?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, customization

I've got a simple question that I just KNOW won't be possible, but here goes:

**Is it possible in ActionScript to customise the look of the very un-user friendly Flash settings dialog that pops up allowing the user to give permissions for network/camera/storage access?**

It makes me crazy that I can make a beautifully crafted Flash app which needs to access to some local resources, with the user's permission, and that God-awful little box appears.  To be clear, I have no problem with WHAT it's doing, just how it LOOKS.  I want to skin it myself.

This is an example of what I mean:

[image]

I've run some focus testing, and users feel intimidated by this thing; they think the site is trying to do something spamful.

My only "solution" has been to try to educate the users with a help button which has a snapshot of the dialog telling them what to do with it.  Not ideal.

Anyway, it's a rant + question, so any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Shane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the best idea I could come up with was a pre-adobe dialog, which explains that this nasty little box will appear after they continue, and explain why it is appearing and that it's ok/safe.

Much better than this dialog just appearing out of nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change the look. You could try something a little more creative though: you can position html elements above the swf embed so you could overlay a new style or mask parts of the dialog apart from the Allow/Deny/Close parts. Then use an external js call from your swf to hide those elements after you know the user has selected something.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I can imagine aligning the HTML so it fits with the flash dialog being very difficult/browser-specific.  Do you have any examples of anyone who has tried this?